# combinatorial proof of summation

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, summation, combinatorial-proofs

Prove $\sum_{i=1}^n2^{i-1}=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}2^i=2^n-1$ combinatorially.

This is easy to prove inductively.  I know that $\sum_{i=0}^n{n\choose i}=2^n$ so maybe change $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}2^i$ to $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=0}^i{i\choose j}$.  I also know that $2^n-1$ is the number of proper subsets in a set of size $n$.

Comment: [This answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/551950/show-that-sum-i-0n-1-2i-2n-1/551973#551973) also provides a combinatorial interpretation. And [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/123855/prove-by-induction-how-do-i-prove-sum-i-0n2i-2n1-1-with-induction/123856#123856) is another one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suppose I have $n$ light switches, numbered $1$ through $n$.  I'd like at least one light on, but other than that I can select any configuration.  How many configurations are there?

Now, for some $i$ with $1\leq i\leq n$, how many configurations are there with the property that switch $i$ is on, but all switches to its right are off?

Comment: 2^n minus the one case where all lights are off, 2^n-1.  2^(n-i),as the switches are specified whereas in the first it can be any one switch.

Comment: @user2008730 $n-i+1$ switches are specified, not $i$ of them.

Answer (score 0):

I have my own combinatorial proof for this.

$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}2^i=2^n-1$

Interpreted as $2^0+2^1+2^2+...+2^{n-1}$

Each increase of $n\ge 1$ by $1$ LHS increases the total by the current total plus one, making the total $(2^{n-1}-1)+2^{n-1}=2(2^{n-1})-1=2^n-1$.

Comment: Isn't this inductive proof?  By "combinatorial proof" most people mean a proof that gives a combinatorial meaning to both sides of the identity.  Your proof is perfectly valid, but it doesn't contain any combinatorics.

Comment: @WillOrrick: I guess so.

Comment: I see now that in the proof above the first paragraph refers to the RHS while the second to the LHS.  Now it makes more sense.